# Java, ошибка границ массива

Tags: java, массивы

При попытке ввести ФИО учащихся выдаёт ошибку границ массива.

```
    // Колличество учащихся
    System.out.print("Количество: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int k = scan.nextInt();

    // Массив имён
    String names[] = new String[k];

    System.out.print("Введите имена: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
        names[i] = scan.nextLine();

    }

    // Массив оценок

    int marks[] = new int[k];
    int sum = 0;
    int length = 0;

    System.out.print("Введите оценки: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {

        marks[i] = scan.nextInt();
        sum += marks[i];
        length = marks.length;

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        System.out.print(names[i] + "\t" + marks[i] + "\n");
    }
    System.out.print("Средняя оценка: " + sum / length);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) {
                   ^              <---
    names[i] = scan.nextLine();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`for (int i = 0; i <= k; i++) { names[i] = scan.nextLine(); }`

Должно быть:
`for(int i = 0; i < k; i++)`,
так как нумерация в массиве начинается с нуля

Comment: Если стоит знак строго ровно, в массив имён набирается три элемента, тогда как оценок набирается четыре. И при выводе получается 3 имени и 4 оценки.